# how to make edge of layer round in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I am using GIMP.
I want to make a new layer (above another layer) with round edges. How to do it? thanks

Comment: For what purpose do the edges of the layer need to be round? I would think you would make objects round, not the layer itself if such a thing is possible

Comment: @ZachSaucier one use case is that. Ipad pro has round edged screen. When I want to show my app on Ipad, I take screenshot of the app(square edges) then in GIMP I add ipad png and drag and drop the screenshot and apply the round edge on the screenshot image layer.

Answer (score 2):

Layers are always rectangular - not only in GIMP, but in all other raster image editing software I know off.

What could restrain the layer shape and for all effects to make it look like it does have rounded colors is to create a layer mask in full white (meaning the opacity of the layer is not changed) but for the corners of the mask, which would be painted black.

Unfortunately, there is no "shortcut" for that in GIMP - so follow the steps bellow. Keep in mind that by setting "Edit->preferences->itnerface>Dynamic keyboard shortcuts" you can assigning a single shortcut for most operations bellow. Asking someone to write you (or write yourself) a Python script to achieve the results is another wya if you are doing this a log.

With your layer selected,

1. on the context menu for layers, `Add Layer Mask...`. Pick "Full
   opacity" (white)
2. on the same menu click on `Mask to Selection`
3. `Select->Feather...`  feather it by the desired radius.
4. `Select->Sharpen`
5. `Select->Feather...` again, but this time y 1 or 2px - in order to avoid aliasing
6. `Select->Invert`
7. Drag the black color (from the toolbox, or from the color selection dialog) to the image. (Easiest way to fill with black, without having to switch to the bucket fill tool)
8. `Select->None`

You are done. Just remember clicking back on the layer thumbnail on the Layer's dialog to ensure you are now editing the layer,instead of the mask.

Comment: I am sorry sir, but I am not getting. I have uploaded the .xcf file to my [drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mlE-ZCN6aWeTBNQzBET2htajg/view?usp=sharing), please look at it. thx

Comment: I'd replace the Feather-Sharpen by a rectangular selection with rounded corners.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher: but that way one have to draw the selection by hand, manually making it match the layer size. The feather/sharpen will work automatically for any layer size.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: It looks like you have to better understand how layer masks work in GIMP - try following the tutorial by PatDavid here: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Layer_Masks/

Comment: No, you do not have to draw the selection manually - you already got the whole layer selected by your previous step Mask to Selection. The rectangular selection tool is initialized with this size automatically, and then you can adjust settings like the rounded corner radius and commit the selection. And if you do this in Subtract mode, you even avoid the final Select->Invert step.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher rectangular selection worked!  